# My OS disappeared (WIN7) on Acer Aspire Lap top including BOOT file

Tags: installation, uninstall, re-installation, remote

Okay, I'm obviously an extream novice with computers no matter what OS! So Whoever responds To my Question must be patient & Take it Easy on me please.   (OKAY) this is what happened  Misplaced my windows BIOS password while moving.

Along with my windows logon Password. Then had the 4 gig of ram stolen out of it. When I finally started to address all these issues,  I first went to staples and bought 2gig of ram compatable with the Acer Aspire 5552-3691. That's all I could afford.

Tried to get past the BIOS Password to no Avail. As I was frantically trying to fix this, In a exhausted state at 3am, I hooked up a 500gb seagate USB Drive thinking I had made a back up on it. Had to leave next day and forgot it was running. I think it removed everything. Long Story Short, A friend of mine tried to make a boot disk. He could'nt get it to boot. Then I remembered a few years ago when I couldn't boot a sony vio LT, That ubuntu 8.04 installed creating its own boot file and ran great.

So he downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and installed it. Problem is when it boots it takes me to a screen that only accepts Ubuntu commands. I have no Idea how to get to a browser or load the Laptop drivers and the commands I tried for 4 hours last night would not work.

Had no Access to internet. I have some severe health issues and is hard to comprehend seemingly hundreds of instructions to make this work.

Last Time I installed Ubuntu It seemed to do most of the configuring for me. I don't Know what I'm Doing wrong But someone please Help Me!!! I've Downloaded Several Types on CD's and some on DVD.

I think most were live Disks. Do I uninstall what did go to HD. Can I do remote desk top with someone who Knows what they are doing, In this limited state. Thank you in advance !!!! SOMEONE ?!!! PLEASE !!!!

Comment: Acer's service guide for your model laptop is [here](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/Manuals/acer/2010/ServiceGuides/SG_Aspire_5252_5552_5552G_20100811.pdf) with instructions on how to reset the BIOS password by shorting two electrical contacts, on page 42.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have installed the server version of Ubuntu, which does not have a graphic user interface.  Ubuntu comes with support for most laptops right out of the box.  Your best solution to get Ubuntu running would be to download the default version of Ubuntu from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

There's a large orange box on the right side, just click that and download the image, burn it, and then boot from that disc.

Instead of installing it, you'd be best using the 'default' boot option, which will allow you to see the ubuntu desktop, which will give you a chance to see if it will work on your laptop or not.  If it does, then you'll be safe in formatting your hard drive (tand installing a fresh copy of ubuntu using the ubuntu installation program.